# Unable to pushViewController after dismissing present view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, pushviewcontroller

I have `FavouriteViewController` in which i have one button on click of button i am presenting a view modally called `LoginViewController` (using storyboard).

On this page(`LoginViewController`), i again have button, on click of that i am dismissing my modal view controller, after dismissing i again comes back to `FavouriteViewController` now on this page when i try to push my view controller it doesn't pushes.

Here is my code snippet,

**------  PART 1  -----**

**FavouriteViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)LoginClicked:(id)sender {
      NSLog(@"--- Navigated to LoginViewController ---");
    //Navigates to `LoginViewController` using storyboard..
}
```

**LoginViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)LoginViaFb:(id)sender{

         NSLog(@"--- Inside LoginViafb ---");
         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

         FavoriteTabViewController *fav=[[FavoriteTabViewController alloc] init];
         [fav Loginsuccessfull];
}
```

**FavouriteViewController.m**

```
-(void)Loginsuccessfull{
    NSLog(@"--- Inside Loginsuccessfull ---");

    UserDetailsViewController *user=[[UserDetailsViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:user animated:NO];
}
```

My Log shows:

```
--- Navigated to LoginViewController ---
--- Inside LoginViafb ---
--- Inside Loginsuccessfull ---
```

**Please help, and thanks in advance.**

**----- PART 2  -----:**

** I also tried:**

Code in my **LoginViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)LoginViaFb:(id)sender{

         NSLog(@"--- Inside LoginViafb ---");
         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

         FavoriteTabViewController *fav=[[FavoriteTabViewController alloc] init];
         fav.GoLogin=@"some values"; 
}
```

and in **FavouriteViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"some values --- %@",some values);

     if ([GoLogin isEqualToString:@"some values"]) {
           NSLog(@"Method called");
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[UserDetailsViewController alloc] init] animated:NO];
    }

}
```

But it still doesn't help, shows `some values --- null`

Comment: xcode showing any warning?

Comment: do get any exception or error. which version of xcode you are using

Comment: I am not getting any error in my log, and i am using xocde 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is way what I said to you.

> FavouriteViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)LoginClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"--- Navigated to LoginViewController ---");

    loginVcObc.logindelegate = self;    
}

 #pragma mark LoginDelegate

 - (void)loginSuccessfull {
        UserDetailsViewController *user=[[UserDetailsViewController alloc] init];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:user animated:NO];
   }
```

> LoginViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol LoginDelegate;    
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController

@property (assign) id <LoginDelegate> logindelegate;

@end

@protocol LoginDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)loginSuccessfull;

@end
```

> LoginViewController.m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@implementation LoginViewController

@synthesize logindelegate;

- (IBAction)LoginViaFb:(id)sender{

     NSLog(@"--- Inside LoginViafb ---");
    if (self.logindelegate) {
       [self.logindelegate loginSuccessfull];
  }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


}
```

Comment: Dude If i don't initialize then how will i call this ?`-(void)Loginsuccessfull`

Comment: I told you can use delegate concept here. Declare protocol in LoginViewController with one method loginsuccessfull, And set that delegate to FavoriteTabViewController. While call LoginViaFb this method before disimissing LoginViewController, call that delegate method.

Comment: @Krunal I written concep,  you can follow that. If not able to understand then let me know.

Comment: yes, i am not getting. can you please show me what code should i write ?

Comment: I wrote, `-(void)someMethod:(Protocol*)someArgument;` in LoginViewController but how to set delegate of this to FavoriteTabViewController ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42098/discussion-between-bhumeshwer-katre-and-krunal)